# Linux shell script to switch user and prompt required information background to script

Tags: shell, scripting, su

I need a sample linux shell script for scenario below:

During interactive session:

```
su user1
Password: <Type password>
```

What I will do is I will save the password in some file (e.g.: `~/pwd.txt`). I need a shell script such that when we execute that script, the password for the target user will be read from the file and automatically passed to `su` and I will then switch to the target user. It isn't necessary to show the prompt, it would be fine if everything gets processed in the background and I just see the switch to the new user directly).

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: *without using except pls..

Comment: A better approach would be to configure `sudo` to allow running the required  command(s) without a password. It can also run an interactive shell as the specified user. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html

Comment: This is a really, really bad idea (you never store passwords in text files if you can possibly avoid it) and sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Please [edit] your question and explain _why_ you want to do this. Tell us what the final objective is. I am sure we can find a better solution.

Comment: Despite being an XY problem, you can easily capture the password and store it in a text file.  If I were to do this I'd add an `alias` for `su`.  The trick is passing that password to `su`.  `su` doesn't have any command-line methods to insert a password (i.e. `su user -p pass123`).  It also doesn't accept passwords piped from stdin (e.g. `echo pass123 > su user` or `su user < pwd.txt`).

Comment: @Bodo that is... a very reasonable suggestion which I should have made in the first place as a mod! I've now deleted our exchange, and thanks for reminding me not to do it in the comments! bad mod!

Comment: Really good related question asked later today which gets to the point: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620731/make-su-read-from-stdin

Answer (score 0):

It's not secured to store your raw password in a file ; but at least this will be an answer for your question.

*Using NOPASSWD in sudoers*

Add the below entry to your sudoers :

```
<your_user> ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su - user1
#Then simply run
sudo -S su - user1
```

*Without  sudoers* : Usefull for non interactive shells

```
su - user1 -c ""  < ~/pwd.txt &>/dev/null
```

`< ~/pwd.txt` Redirect your password stored in ~/pwd.txt to su command.

`&>/dev/null` Redirect both stdout and sterr to >/dev/null.

**## BETTER ## :**

You can use **gpg** tool to encrypt your password :

```
    # Encrypt your password with choosing a passphrase :
    gpg -c ~/pwd.txt 
    # Remove your raw password file :
    rm -f ~/pwd.txt.gpg
```

Now when trying to su use the above to decrypt your **password** :

```
su - user1 -c ""  <<< "$(gpg -q -d ~/pwd.txt.gpg 2>/dev/null)" &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Slight problem here.  When the password file is finished, `EOF` is sent to `su` via `stdin`.  When `su` reads `EOF` it quits.  So while this may log you in, it will log you out immediately.  It works with a `-c` command, but not if you want to stay in an interactive shell.

Comment: Yes exactly i have added that it will not work for it shell.

Comment: Above suggestion "su - user1 -c ""  < ~/pwd.txt &>/dev/null" not working
Can some one help me on the topic to fulfill my requirement.
Requirement:
<upon running some unix command>, it prompts for passphrase: <now, i have to enter passphrase>.
Same thing i need to get from a small shell script. As i have to use it in multiple areas of my code.